# timeout error handling with node.js and express

Tags: node.js, express, timeout

In my app using node.js and Express I've got a problem with handling timeout error during my request to some 3rd party shop's url. Sometimes shop's server is overloaded and I get a timeout error.
That's my code:

```
request(url, function (error, response, html) {
        console.log("response.statusCode: " + response.statusCode);
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log("OK");
            //some code
        }
    });
```

I managed to handle errors like 404 but I don't know how to handle timeout connection error. I've read about [connect-timeout](https://github.com/expressjs/timeout) module for node.js, but I think it is more for for 'in app' requests, rather than for request to 3rd party url. Do I think correctly? What does time after which I get timeout error depends on?

Comment: What is `request`? If you are use [`request`](https://github.com/request/request) module then you can check `err.code === 'ETIMEDOUT'`.

Comment: Yes, I'm using request module and your comment helped me a lot. Thanks!